# AJW-Export date formating in CSV is off 6 hours

Tags: date, sql

I'm using ajw_export for my CSV,

I have:

```
DATE_FORMAT(from_unixtime(exp_channel_data.field_id_454), '%h:%i') AS Start_Time,
```

works but shows time with 6 hour difference.

I have tried:

```
DATE_FORMAT(DATE_ADD(from_unixtime(exp_channel_data.field_id_454), '%h:%i')INTERVAL 6 HOUR) AS Start_Time
```

but it gives me erros in my sql.

Can anyone tell me what Am'I doing wrong?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

After playing around and learning about SQL I have found solution . It works. For thouse who are strangling here it is. Please NOTE the difference from the above.

```
DATE_FORMAT(DATE_ADD(from_unixtime(cd.field_id_454), INTERVAL 6 HOUR),'%h:%i %p') AS 'Start Time',
```

Answer (score 0):

Could it be something with time zones? Maybe try doing

```
SET time_zone = 'America/Denver'
```

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/930900/how-to-set-time-zone-of-mysql